# Can I apply timezone changes to my UTC date in SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, localization

So in SQL server I have been storing my dates as UTC, I also have a localized timezone in the format of 'AUS Eastern Standard Time', for example.

Is it possible to calculate the correct datetime with just information in Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide you environment info so I am proposing this for sql server and windows server. 
There is no simple method to do this. As far as I know SQL server does not have time zones it can access. However, Windows does have this information. You could access this in SQL with a SQL CLR user defined table valued function using the time zone info class from .net. Then you just have to add the time zone offset minutes from the CLR function to the UTC date.